# Prove $\sin(x)^3+\cos(x)^3 \leq 1$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I already know:

$$\cos(x)\sin(x)\leq \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\cos(x)+\sin(x)\leq \sqrt{2}$$

How can I use these to prove inequality $\sin(x)^3+\cos(x)^3 \leq 1$? I tried to use binomial expansion, but this doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure with your inequalities?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 10):

$$\sin^3x\le \sin^2x\tag1\label{1}$$
$$\cos^3x\le \cos^2x\tag2\label{2}$$
Add \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} to get the result.

Comment: Is that because |cos(x)|≤1? (And same for sine)

Comment: @aradarbel10, Yes

Comment: @aradarbel10 ... and $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$

Comment: You don't need those absolute values, do you ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust, No, I don't , but it shows that something stronger is true.

Comment: For rigor, don't you need to prove that the equality occurs simultaneously for the two inequalities?

Comment: @Quanto, No, I don't need to show that. Our purpose is served even if the inequalities are strict or equality don't hold simultaneously.

Comment: I thought, with $a \le c$ and $b \le d$, one could only conclude $a+c < b + d$, not $a+c \le b + d$ unless there is the equality simultaneity.

Comment: @Quanto, $a+c<b+d\implies a+c\le b+d$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but a comment which graph cannot be edited in the comments section.

No need to add something to Martund's smart proof (which can be generalized).

A stronger inequality :
$$-1\leq\cos^n(x)+\sin^n(x)\leq 1\qquad n\geq 2$$

[image]

Comment: Hi Jean ! *Happy New Year !*

Answer (score 0):

Use $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ to show $\sin^3(x)+\cos^3(x) = (\sin(x) + \cos(x))(1-\sin(x)\cos(x))$ and then apply the (corrected) inequalities.